# How relevant today to use JVM?

Tags: java, python, jvm

Don't we have enough amount of compilers today (for various platforms) ? Python for example - it is considered as a crossplatform langauge.

Comment: On the contrary, there are plenty of system administration and network monitoring tools written in Java, and not dependent on any particular architecture. ManageEngine OpManager, to name one that I use. There are also development environments, like Eclipse, and entire suites like OpenOffice.

Comment: For example why do Eclipse had been written for virtual machine, why don't use usual compiled language ? Eclipse needs only on PC.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, @boot13, there are also [other programming languages running on the JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages). (And I don't think OpenOffice runs on the JVM, though early versions did use Java for scripting or something like that.)

Comment: Why do you think folks using Linux or Mac OS X don't use Eclipse? (By the way, this question is off topic here.)

Comment: Do you know how much work creating a compiler actually is?

Comment: @Arjan, PC - I meanеt personal computer, a desktop computer. Where is such topic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is *a lot* of such code. Every day you use dozens of websites which need this. Although these days they're mostly written in JavaScript and sometimes Flash's ActionScript, but the general idea remains the same.

(Remember that one of the primary uses of Java was for applets in websites – similar to Flash later and JavaScript today.)

There are also many more architectures than "PC and mobile". Over the past two decades, PCs have used a few dozen different CPU architectures – for example: [68000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amiga), [PowerPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Macintosh), x86, amd64, Alpha, [SPARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARCstation), [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi), ARM64 – and that's just the *popular* ones.

So that creates problems in *distributing* the compiled programs.

With native code, *every* such website's owners would have to distribute many different versions of the same program – one for every CPU architecture (remember, it's not just two), or maybe even for every OS × CPU combination (as different operating systems have different services, different APIs, different calling conventions on the same CPU).

(Even within the same architecture, many programs compiled for Intel i686 won't run on i486 even though that's technically the same x86 – but with different features. For example, Debian Linux compiles everything for i486, so it won't make use of any modern CPU features which means programs may be a little slower. On the other hand, Arch Linux is compiled for i686, so it won't run at all on an old i486 CPU.)

With bytecode, Sun/Oracle can distribute JVMs for all architectures, and webmasters don't need to do anything other than that – they only need *one* .jar file for everyone.